# Thread-safety considerations with IDictionary and ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, clr

This question is primarily academic - I understand this is not necessarily practical code.

Consider this code, where thread-safety is a concern:

```
// In the constructor
IDictionary<string, string> myDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

...

// Elsewhere in the class
myDictionary.Add("foo", "bar");
```

**My overall question**: How is this handled from a concurrency point of view?

Would this be considered thread-safe, and if so, why? I ask because the (known) thread-safe method is `AddOrUpdate` - I don't have access to this with `IDictionary`. Is the CLR "smart enough" to know what's going on here? Is there a property of inheritance I am missing here, could the `.Add` call be mutated into an `.AddOrUpdate` call "under the hood"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CLR is not related here. `ConcurrentDictionary` implements interface `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` implicitly, and you can see what it does for `IDictionary.Add` [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs):

```
void IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
{
     if (!TryAdd(key, value))
     {
          throw new ArgumentException(GetResource("ConcurrentDictionary_KeyAlreadyExisted"));
    }
}
```

So it calls `TryAdd` ("safe" method of `ConcurrentDictionary`) and if unable to add key - throws exception that entry with such key already exists.

It's still "thread-safe", because you cannot have nasty side effects which you will using regular dictionary and adding items there from multiple threads. If you prepare for such exception - you can safely add items with `Add` to such dictionary from multiple threads.